# SQL count distinct

Tags: sql, count, group-by, distinct

How can I do a count distinct selection? Basically I have all these charges and I want to count only the number of distinct employees involved with that charge. (I already have other fields for the group by)

Comment: `select count(distinct id) from table` did not work? what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: post that as the answer, I had no idea how to use the distinct keyword

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employeeid) FROM ....
```

Comment: Is this TSQL? Or what versions of SQL can do this?

Comment: i believe it is a standard and it works in all implementations i found on SQLFiddle (including SQLite, Oracle and Postgres, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Simple as: `select count(distinct(field)) from table`

Live sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81379/2/3

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `DISTINCT` in a `COUNT` (in TSQL):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(employee)) ...
```